# React: clear input item after click doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to clear input item after click on Add. It's on line 49 but doesn't work:
Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wbn3ms?file=src%2FStepsForm.js

`setForm({date: '', distance: ''});`

Could you please help why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `form.date`,`form.distance` from `form` state to `value` attribute in **date** and **distance** input fields

```
<input id="date" name="date" onChange={handleChange} value={form.date} />

<input id="distance" name="distance" onChange={handleChange} value={form.distance}/>
```

without the `value` attribute, the input fields are [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#:%7E:text=In%20a%20controlled%20component%2C%20form,form%20values%20from%20the%20DOM.).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set `value={form.date}` and `value={form.distance}` on those inputs, so changes done into the state don't get reflected back into the input elements.